# Is there a word-processor plugin for stackoverflow's markdown

Tags: discussion, markdown

I have started to grow accustomed to using SE's markdown system, and I love the way it looks. I was wondering, if there was a word-processor, or word processor plugin that uses the same markdown system as SE?

(Also, I was hoping that in addition to markdown, it would have support for the mathJax that is used on math.SE)

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange's markdown is just a variation of [standard Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), so the [*MultiMarkdown* editor](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) may be enough of what you want.

Other options:

- [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/) - a "fully featured Markdown editor with live preview".  [Developed by a SO aficionado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924828/331508).
- [Emacs Markdown Mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) - a plugin for the common programming editor.
- See, also, ["Are there any text editors which are Markdown aware and provide spell checking features?"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150928070650/http://superuser.com/questions/235519/are-there-any-text-editors-which-are-markdown-aware-and-provide-spell-checking-f)
- You can always make your own word-processor, that uses Stack Exchange's exact syntax, by wrapping a GUI around [Markdown Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/), which is Stack Exchange's implementation of its custom markdown.